# Adding lambda methods to class

Tags: python, class, lambda

I have class A:

```
class A:
    a = 2
    b = 3
    c = 4
```

And I added to it methods for getting each member (get_a, get_b, get_c) by

```
for attrib in ('a', 'b', 'c'):
    f = lambda self: getattr(self, attrib)
    setattr(A, 'get_'+attrib, f)
```

Surprisingly calling each method on created instance:

```
a = A()
print(a.get_a())
print(a.get_b())
print(a.get_c())
```

Results in

```
4
4
4
```

Not in as I expected

```
2
3
4
```

I figured out that expanding the loop to 3 uses of `setattr` do the thing, but why? Why rolling up 3 uses of `setattr` changes anything?